# How to do validation and display message before form submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple rows of HTML input elements with type number. Each row has four input fields and I want to add validation so that any input field should not allow a value lesser than the field on it's left side (in the same row).

I want to add this same validation for every row.

I want to do this validation before form submission and display error message. (before form submission/submit button is clicked)

The leftmost row should not allow a value less than zero (as it doesn't have any input field on it's left).

Can you please suggest me how I can do this using the sample jsfiddle: [Error message when text field has a value out of range](https://jsfiddle.net/fiddle300/9c7nkqwy/)

(I tried to do this using "min" option in "input" tag but works only after submit button is clicked.)

Same code as in fiddle:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TestPage</title>
        <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                addPlusSign();
                $(".btn1").click(function(){
                    $(".expand1").toggle();
                    var btn1Text = $(".btn1").text();
                    if(btn1Text.indexOf("+") > -1){
                        var temp = btn1Text.replace(/\+|\-/ig, '-');
                        $(".btn1").text(temp);
                    } else if (btn1Text.indexOf("-") > -1){
                        var temp = btn1Text.replace(/\+|\-/ig, '+');
                        $(".btn1").text(temp);
                    }
                });
            })
            function addPlusSign(){
                if($(".expand1")){
                    var btn1Text = $(".btn1").text();
                    $(".btn1").text(btn1Text + " [+]");
                }
            }
            $(function () {
                $('.admin-form')
                //we need to save values from all inputs with class 'admin-input'
                .find(':input.admin-input')
                .each(function () {
                    //save old value in each input's data cache
                    $(this).data('oldValue', $(this).val())
                })
                .end()
                .submit(function (ev) {
                    var changed = false;
                    $(':input.admin-input', this).filter(function () {
                        if($(this).val() != $(this).data('oldValue')){
                            changed = true;
                        }
                    });
                    if($(this).hasClass('changed') && (!changed)){
                        alert("None of the thresholds were changed!");
                        ev.preventDefault()
                    }
                    if($(this).hasClass('changed') && changed){
                        var allowSubmit = window.confirm("You have set a unique threshold for one or more sub-elements below. Are you sure you want to reset them all?")
                        if (!allowSubmit)
                        ev.preventDefault()
                    }
                });
            });
            $(document).on('input', '.admin-input', function(){
                $(this).closest('form').addClass('changed');
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            .expand1 { display: none;
            }
            .btn1 { cursor: pointer;
            }
                body {
                background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
                font: 15px Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            }
                table#t02, #t02 th, #t02 td {
                border: none;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                font-size:95%;
                font-weight:normal;
            }
                #button1{
                position: relative;
                top:50px;
                left:35%;
                color: white;
                background-color: rgb(0,89,132);
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            #button2{
                position: relative;
                top:50px;
                left:50%;
                color: white;
                background-color: rgb(0,89,132);
                font-weight: bold;
            }
                input[type=number] {
                max-width: 50px;
            }
            html {
                overflow-y: scroll;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" method="post" class="admin-form">
            <div style="float:left; width:50%">
                <br />
                <br />
                <table id="t02" class="table2">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="padding:0 30px 0 0;"></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th style="padding:0 10px 0 0;">Green</th>
                        <th colspan="3" style="padding:0 10px 0 0">Yellow</th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th style="padding:0 10px 0 0">Red</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="btn1" style="padding:0 30px 0 0;"><b>Row1 (%)</b></td>
                        <td>&lt</td>
                        <td style="padding:0 10px 0 0"><input type="number", class="admin-input", name="row1_good_high", value="5", size="3", maxlength="3"></td>
                        <td><input type="number", class="admin-input", name="row1_warning_low", value="5", size="3", maxlength="3"></td>
                        <td>-</td>
                        <td style="padding:0 10px 0 0"><input type="number", class="admin-input", name="row1_warning_high", value="15", size="3", maxlength="3"></td>
                        <td>&gt</td>
                        <td style="padding:0 10px 0 0"><input type="number", class="admin-input", name="row1_critical_low", value="15", size="3", maxlength="3"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" class="expand1">Sub Row</td>
                        <td class="expand1">&lt</td>
                        <td class="expand1"><input type="number", name="row1_good_high_Sub Row", value="5", size="3", maxlength="3"></td>
                        <td class="expand1"><input type="number", name="row1_warning_low_Sub Row", value="5", size="3", maxlength="3"></td>
                        <td class="expand1">-</td>
                        <td class="expand1"><input type="number", name="row1_warning_high_Sub Row", value="15", size="3", maxlength="3"></td>
                        <td class="expand1">&gt</td>
                        <td class="expand1"><input type="number", name="row1_critical_low_Sub Row", value="15", size="3", maxlength="3"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both">
                <input type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit the change?')" name="submitButton" value="Submit" id="button1" style="height:50px; width:100px"/>
                <input title="Set thresholds to baseline thresholds" type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to set all thresholds to the baseline thresholds?')" name="resetButton" value="Reset" id="button2" style="height:50px; width:100px"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you consider using 1 of the many Jquery Validation Plugins? maybe something like this: http://formvalidation.io/examples/

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried checking through the list of links that are there on this page, but couldn't find one that might help me with this question. I specifically checked "Validating fields that depend on each other" as it looked relevant but it's about date and checking both start/end date again after one of them is changed. I don't know JQuery/JS much so it's quite possible that I might have missed something from those links.

Answer (score 0):

goog validation jquery plugin: http://jqueryvalidation.org/
you can define dependency like this:

```
$(".selector").validate({
  rules: {
    contact: {
      required: true,
      email: {
        depends: function(element) {
          return $("#contactform_email").is(":checked");
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your replies, Yaco Zaragoza and miralong.

Finally I was able to come up with following which does what I wanted:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TestPage</title>
        <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                addPlusSign();
                $(".btn1").click(function(){
                    $(".expand1").toggle();
                    var btn1Text = $(".btn1").text();
                    if(btn1Text.indexOf("+") > -1){
                        var temp = btn1Text.replace(/\+|\-/ig, '-');
                        $(".btn1").text(temp);
                    } else if (btn1Text.indexOf("-") > -1){
                        var temp = btn1Text.replace(/\+|\-/ig, '+');
                        $(".btn1").text(temp);
                    }
                });

                $('[id^="number"]').focusout(function() {
                    var current_field_name = this.id;
                    if (current_field_name.indexOf("_1") > -1) {
                        var good_high = Number(document.getElementById(current_field_name).value);
                        if (good_high < 0) {
                            alert(good_high + " is out of valid range!");
                            document.getElementById(current_field_name).focus();
                        }
                    } else if (current_field_name.indexOf("_2") > -1) {
                        var warning_low = Number(document.getElementById(current_field_name).value);
                        var previous_field_name_1 = current_field_name.replace(/2$/, "1");
                        var good_high = Number(document.getElementById(previous_field_name_1).value);
                        if (warning_low < good_high) {
                            alert(warning_low + " is out of valid range!");
                            document.getElementById(current_field_name).focus();
                        }
                    } else if (current_field_name.indexOf("_3") > -1) {
                        var warning_high = Number(document.getElementById(current_field_name).value);
                        var previous_field_name_1 = current_field_name.replace(/3$/, "1");
                        var good_high = Number(document.getElementById(previous_field_name_1).value);
                        var previous_field_name_2 = current_field_name.replace(/3$/, "2");
                        var warning_low = Number(document.getElementById(previous_field_name_2).value);
                        if (warning_high < warning_low) {
                            alert(warning_high + " is out of valid range!");
                            document.getElementById(current_field_name).focus();
                        }
                    } else if (current_field_name.indexOf("_4") > -1) {
                        var critical_low = Number(document.getElementById(current_field_name).value);
                        var previous_field_name_1 = current_field_name.replace(/4$/, "1");
                        var good_high = Number(document.getElementById(previous_field_name_1).value);
                        var previous_field_name_2 = current_field_name.replace(/4$/, "2");
                        var warning_low = Number(document.getElementById(previous_field_name_2).value);
                        var previous_field_name_3 = current_field_name.replace(/4$/, "3");
                        var warning_high = Number(document.getElementById(previous_field_name_3).value);
                        if (critical_low < warning_high) {
                            alert(critical_low + " is out of valid range!");
                            document.getElementById(current_field_name).focus();
                        }
                    }
                });
            })
            function addPlusSign(){
                if($(".expand1")){
                    var btn1Text = $(".btn1").text();
                    $(".btn1").text(btn1Text + " [+]");
                }
            }
            $(function () {
                $('.admin-form')
                //we need to save values from all inputs with class 'admin-input'
                .find(':input.admin-input')
                .each(function () {
                    //save old value in each input's data cache
                    $(this).data('oldValue', $(this).val())
                })
                .end()
                .submit(function (ev) {
                    var changed = false;
                    $(':input.admin-input', this).filter(function () {
                        if($(this).val() != $(this).data('oldValue')){
                            changed = true;
                        }
                    });
                    if($(this).hasClass('changed') && (!changed)){
                        alert("None of the thresholds were changed!");
                        ev.preventDefault()
                    }
                    if($(this).hasClass('changed') && changed){
                        var allowSubmit = window.confirm("You have set a unique threshold for one or more sub-elements below. Are you sure you want to reset them all?")
                        if (!allowSubmit)
                        ev.preventDefault()
                    }
                });
            });
            $(document).on('input', '.admin-input', function(){
                $(this).closest('form').addClass('changed');
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            .expand1 { display: none;
            }
            .btn1 { cursor: pointer;
            }
                body {
                background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
                font: 15px Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            }
                table#t02, #t02 th, #t02 td {
                border: none;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                font-size:95%;
                font-weight:normal;
            }
                #button1{
                position: relative;
                top:50px;
                left:35%;
                color: white;
                background-color: rgb(0,89,132);
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            #button2{
                position: relative;
                top:50px;
                left:50%;
                color: white;
                background-color: rgb(0,89,132);
                font-weight: bold;
            }
                input[type=number] {
                max-width: 50px;
            }
            html {
                overflow-y: scroll;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" method="post" class="admin-form">
            <div style="float:left; width:50%">
                <br />
                <br />
                <table id="t02" class="table2">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="padding:0 30px 0 0;"></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th style="padding:0 10px 0 0;">Green</th>
                        <th colspan="3" style="padding:0 10px 0 0">Yellow</th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th style="padding:0 10px 0 0">Red</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding:0 30px 0 0;">Row1</td>
                        <td>&lt</td>
                        <td style="padding:0 10px 0 0"><input type="number", name="row1_good_high", value="30", size="3", maxlength="3", id="number42_1"></td>
                        <td><input type="number", name="row1_warning_low", value="30", size="3", maxlength="3", id="number42_2"></td>
                        <td>-</td>
                        <td style="padding:0 10px 0 0"><input type="number", name="row1_warning_high", value="60", size="3", maxlength="3", id="number42_3"></td>
                        <td>&gt</td>
                        <td style="padding:0 10px 0 0"><input type="number", name="row1_critical_low", value="60", size="3", maxlength="3", id="number42_4"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding:0 30px 0 0;">SubRow</td>
                        <td>&lt</td>
                        <td style="padding:0 10px 0 0"><input type="number", name="subrow_good_high", value="30", size="3", maxlength="3", id="number12_1"></td>
                        <td><input type="number", name="subrow_warning_low", value="30", size="3", maxlength="3", id="number12_2"></td>
                        <td>-</td>
                        <td style="padding:0 10px 0 0"><input type="number", name="subrow_warning_high", value="60", size="3", maxlength="3", id="number12_3"></td>
                        <td>&gt</td>
                        <td style="padding:0 10px 0 0"><input type="number", name="subrow_critical_low", value="60", size="3", maxlength="3", id="number12_4"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both">
                <input type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit the change?')" name="submitButton" value="Submit" id="button1" style="height:50px; width:100px"/>
                <input title="Set thresholds to baseline thresholds" type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to set all thresholds to the baseline thresholds?')" name="resetButton" value="Reset" id="button2" style="height:50px; width:100px"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```